# jssor slider transition dont work

Tags: slider, transition, jssor

I have problem with jssor slider. It only show me first photo. I think the problem is in the responsive code. 
I want make full width and full height slider, also fully responsive. When open on smaller devices it cut photo. Please help.

Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Slider with Slideshow Example - Jssor Slider, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade
            {$Duration:1200,x:1,$Delay:50,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$Opacity:2}
            ];

            var options = {
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        });

        //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        if (windowWidth) {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
            var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

            var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
            if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
                scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
            }

            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }

    ScaleSlider();

    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end


    </script>

    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->

     <!-- ORIGINAL SLIDER!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
        height: 300px;"> END!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->

        <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">

        <!-- use 'margin: 0 auto;' to auto center element in parent container -->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="margin: 0 auto;" >
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;  height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u=image src="../img/landscape/01.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="../img/landscape/02.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="../img/landscape/03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="../img/landscape/04.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">jquery content slider</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Slider with Slideshow Example - Jssor Slider, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#fff; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade
            { $Duration: 1200, x: 1, $Delay: 50, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

            var options = {
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var windowWidth = $(window).width();

                if (windowWidth) {
                    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
                    var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

                    var scaleWidth = windowWidth;
                    if (originalWidth / windowWidth > originalHeight / windowHeight) {
                        scaleWidth = Math.ceil(windowHeight / originalHeight * originalWidth);
                    }

                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(scaleWidth);
                }
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });


    </script>

    <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">
            <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
            <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
            <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">

                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                    <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Slides Container -->
                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px;  height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/01.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/02.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/03.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/04.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">jquery content slider</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```